# How to open a URL from Tcl/Tk on Linux

Tags: linux, url, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I cause the browser to open a given URL from Tcl/Tk on Linux?

I'm using this proc on Windows, but I don't know what to do on Linux.

```
proc open_url {url} {
    eval exec [auto_execok start] $url
}

#example call:
open_url http://example.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xdg-open` on Linux.

```
 exec xdg-open $url
```

There is some discussion here: [Invoking Browsers](http://wiki.tcl.tk/557) on the Tcl wiki.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks! I'd up-vote you if I could. (This site has weird rules.)